# What is the Rails 4 replacement for association proxy?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I'm in the process of upgrading a Rails 3.2 app to Rails 4.2.0.  In the 3.2 app, I used a generic controller method to add a model object to an association, as follows:

```
parentResource.association(associationKey).proxy.push resource
```

So if I had a model Thing, and Thing has_many :collection_things, for instance, then parentResource would be an instance of Thing and associationKey would be :collection_things.  This method call added *resource* (here, an instance of CollectionThing) to the Thing.collection_things association (I could have used "send", but that would have potentially allowed any model method to be called, by sending it as a parameter).  I'm not sure this was the best way to do it, but it allowed me to handle many different types of associations with a single controller method.

This no longer works in Rails 4.  It looks like, in Rails 4, I need to obtain the Thing's

```
ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy
```

and call push, but the call to

```
parentResource.association(associationKey)
```

that worked in my 3.2 app returns an instance of

```
ActiveRecord::Associations::HasManyAssociation
```

which no longer has a proxy method, so I get a NoMethodError.

Any thoughts on how to best do this in Rails 4?  I know I can obtain the CollectionProxy using something like

```
parentResource.send association_name
```

but is there a way to do it that is more along the lines of what I was doing in the 3.2 version of the app?

Answer (score 0):

OK, after much poking around, I found what appears to be the Rails 4 way of doing it:

```
t.association(:collection_things).insert_record resource
```

and delete works as it did in 3.2:

```
t.association(:collection_things).delete resource
```

I've tested it in pry, and it appears to be working as expected.